# How to create Material UI component in Om Clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript, om

First of all, this https://github.com/taylorSando/om-material-ui doesn't work with latest React/Material UI.
The main reason, I think, is this warning in console:

`Warning: Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or JSX instead. See: https://fb.me/react-legacyfactory`

I've also tried to create component "manually":

```
(ns om-test.core
  (:require [om.core :as om :include-macros true]
            [om-tools.dom :as dom :include-macros true]
            [om-tools.core :refer-macros [defcomponent]]
            [om-material-ui.core :as mui :include-macros true]))

(enable-console-print!)

(defonce app-state (atom {:text "Hello Chestnut!"}))

(defn main []
  (om/root
    (fn [app owner]
      (reify
        om/IRender
        (render [_]
          (dom/div (dom/element js/MaterialUI.Paper {} "Hello")
                   (mui/paper {} "Hello"))
          )))
    app-state
    {:target (. js/document (getElementById "app"))}))
```

So, both of these approaches produces same warning above.

There has been obviously some changes with React. It suggests to create components programatically as:

```
var React = require('react');
var MyComponent = React.createFactory(require('MyComponent'));

function render() {
  return MyComponent({ foo: 'bar' });
}
```

So how do I create Material UI component inside Om render function, or maybe better How do I create React component inside Om render function, in general?

By Material UI I mean this https://github.com/callemall/material-ui

My dependencies

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-3058" :scope "provided"]
                 [ring "1.3.2"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.1.4"]
                 [compojure "1.3.2"]
                 [enlive "1.1.6"]
                 [org.omcljs/om "0.9.0"]
                 [environ "1.0.0"]
                 [http-kit "2.1.19"]
                 [prismatic/om-tools "0.3.11"]
                 [om-material-ui "0.1.1" :exclusions [org.clojure/clojurescript
                                                      org.clojure/clojure]]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay I eventually figured out.

1. Build latest version of Material UI with this: https://github.com/taylorSando/om-material-ui/tree/master/build-mui. Note: No need to build CSS in current version (0.10.4)
2. Include built `material.js` into your HTML file. Again, no need to include CSS.
3. Avoid loading React twice https://github.com/taylorSando/om-material-ui#avoid-loading-react-twice

Now the code for **Om**:

```
(ns material-ui-test.core
  (:require [om.core :as om :include-macros true]
            [om.dom :as dom :include-macros true]))

(enable-console-print!)

(defonce app-state (atom {:text "Hello Chestnut!"}))

(def ^:dynamic *mui-theme*
  (.getCurrentTheme (js/MaterialUI.Styles.ThemeManager.)))

(defn main []
  (om/root
    (fn [app owner]
      (reify
        om/IRender
        (render [_]
          (let [ctor (js/React.createFactory
                       (js/React.createClass
                         #js
                             {:getDisplayName    (fn [] "muiroot-context")
                              :childContextTypes #js {:muiTheme js/React.PropTypes.object}
                              :getChildContext   (fn [] #js {:muiTheme *mui-theme*})
                              :render            (fn []
                                                   (dom/div nil
                                                            (dom/h1 nil (:text app))
                                                            (js/React.createElement js/MaterialUI.Slider)))}))]
            (ctor. nil)))))
    app-state
    {:target (. js/document (getElementById "app"))}))
```

If you used just `(js/React.createElement js/MaterialUI.Slider)` without `:getChildContext` etc. it would throw error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of undefined`

This is because of how current MaterialUI works. Read "Usage" part here: http://material-ui.com/#/customization/themes

Code for **Reagent** is bit more elegant. But I've used here namespace

`[material-ui.core :as ui :include-macros true]`

copy-pasted from this example project: https://github.com/tuhlmann/reagent-material

```
(def ^:dynamic *mui-theme*
  (.getCurrentTheme (js/MaterialUI.Styles.ThemeManager.)))

(defn main-panel []
  (let [active-panel (rf/subscribe [:active-panel])]
    (r/create-class
      {:display-name "Main Panel"

       :child-context-types
                     #js {:muiTheme js/React.PropTypes.object}

       :get-child-context
                     (fn [this]
                       #js {:muiTheme *mui-theme*})
       :reagent-render
                     (fn []
                       [ui/Slider {:name "slide1"}])})))
```

**EDIT:** I released library, which greatly simplifies whole process.

Library: https://github.com/madvas/cljs-react-material-ui

Example app: https://github.com/madvas/cljs-react-material-ui-example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Material UI but [React Widgets](http://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/docs/#/). Here is the [wrapper](https://github.com/bensu/om-widgets) I needed to write for om:

```lisp
(defn dropdown-list
  [data owner {:keys [val-key menu-key id-key label-key props]}]
  (reify
    om/IRender
    (render [_]
      (let [menu (-get data menu-key)]
        (js/React.createElement js/ReactWidgets.DropdownList 
          (-> {:defaultValue (-> (find-by-key menu id-key (-get data     val-key))
                               (-get label-key)) 
               :data (mapv #(-get % label-key) menu)
               :onChange (fn [new-val]
                           (let [new-id (-> (find-by-key menu label-    key new-val)
                                          (-get id-key))]
                             (om/update! data val-key new-id)))}
            (merge props)
            clj->js))))))
```

So, in general, you need to get the React class (`js/ReactWidgets.DropdownList`) and call `js/Readt.createElement` while passing the props on `render`.